# Group last added content from all category (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, joomla

My query:

```
  SELECT a.id, a.title, a.introtext, a.fulltext, a.created, a.image, a.catid, a.sectionid
  FROM jos_content AS a 
  LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS c 
  ON a.catid = c.id 
  WHERE a.state = 1
  AND c.published = 1
  AND ( publish_up = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR publish_up <= "2012-02-08 11:10:25" )
  AND ( publish_down = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR publish_down >= "2012-02-08 11:10:25" ) 
  AND a.access <= 0

  AND a.catid = 41

  ORDER BY a.created DESC, a.id DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 1
```

For 30 category I have 30 request in MySQL (change AND a.catid = 21, AND a.catid = 42 and over).

How to group all categories (21, 41, 42) and select last added content from jos_content

Answer (score 0):

Are categories assigned to the same section?
If yes, simply select sectionid instead of catid.